# Gmap - You must enter a location in the field

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I'm using EE 2.8.1 and Gmap 3.2.7.  I'm suddenly getting a message "You must enter a location in the "custom field" field" when I try and save an entry.  This is happening even though we have entered a location;

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to have been a recent change in the gmap API. See if [this thread](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/248463/) can shed some light on your issue.

Apparently changing

```
$this->EE->theme_loader->javascript('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true');
```

to

```
$this->EE->theme_loader->javascript('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&sensor=true');
```

in `gmap/ft.gmap.php` might help.

Comment: Hi Ingmar, that looks like it's fixed it, thanks for your help.

Comment: Worked for me as well!